# Only I-frames are correctly encoded while recording H264 video

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, h.264, raspbian

I'm recording video with a Raspberry Pi 2 and camera module in a Python script, using the `picamera` package. See minimal example below:

```
import picamera
import time

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution=(730, 1296), framerate=49) as camera:
    camera.rotation=270
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    camera.start_recording('test.h264')
    time.sleep(3)
    camera.stop_recording()
    camera.stop_preview()
```

### Results

The result is a video with bad encoding:

- first frame is ok
- in the next 59 frames the scene is barely visible, almost all green or purple (not clear what's making change between the two colors)
- frame number 61 is ok

Basically only the I-frames are correctly encoded. This was clarified experimenting different values of the `intra_period` parameter of the `start_recording` function.

### Notes and attempts already made

First and foremost, I was using the same code to correctly record video in the past on the same Raspberry Pi and camera. It's not clear to me if the problem appeared when reinstalling the complete image, during updates, installation of other packages...

Also:

- if I don't set the `resolution` parameter and rotation, the camera works fine
- several video players have been tested on the same and on other machines, and processing frame by frame with OpenCV, it is really a problem in the video file
- `mjpeg` format works fine
- the same problem happens setting `sensor_mode=5`

### Questions

The main question is how to correctly record video at a set resolution, by correction of the code above or a workaround.
Secondary question: I'm curious to know what could cause such behaviour.

Comment: Well, the encoding work should be done by the GPU, in fact I can see the CPU load around 1% while recording, with a peak of about 4% at the very beginning of the script.